Windows 10 Slow Boot, require help to check Windows Performance Analyzer Logs
I have a computer that has been really slow in the boot phase.The computer has an SSD and once entered into the system it is fast and has no problems, but starting up takes more than 10 minutes every time, both when turned off and with restart.
I recorded the entire boot process with Windows Performance Recorder but unfortunately I can't figure out where the problem is. I put the various recordings below and I thank in advance anyone who will help me
https://mega.nz/folder/BJtklYDI#F5E5v8NQfurYqtL0547-fQ
enter image description here

10 min, really! What is your machine configuration?

"I put the various recordings below..." Where? BTW, a common cause is antimalware scanning system before boot completes. However, Windows requires antimalware.

It's an HP i3 laptop with 8GB of RAM and 250GB SSD. If I format it the computer is also fast at startup but having several programs and data inside I wanted to keep it that way.
I also say that I removed everything from startup from both task manager and msconfig

@DrMoishePippik I added the link now, it's finishing loading inside. 5 minutes and the upload will be finished. UPDATE: upload complete

@DrMoishePippik what exactly should I post? inside the file there are many diagrams
UPDATE: i have upload a pic in my post

@NicolaBaldazzi Windows 10 and above doesn't need third party antivirus/anti-malware programs since Windows Defender is on par, or exceeds, top third-party programs. It may be more efficient [quicker] to do a repair install, then see if the issue still exists. To do, download the Windows install ISO, extract it to a directory, then run setup.exe while booted to Windows. choosing to keep all files.

@JW0914, agreed on all you state, however Defender (MsMpEng.exe) does take quite a few minutes on my Windows to scan files before system comes up to speed. After hibernation or boot, it can take 10 minutes for that to complete, during which time response is downright l e t h a r g i c.

@DrMoishePippik I've never experienced that on Windows 10 or 11, but I have all SATA/mSATA SSDs - my Alienware 18 boots to Windows in ~10s, and with log in, am at the Desktop in <60s. Ten minutes for Windows Defender to scan what's being loaded seems really abnormal and not working as designed - have you tried a repair install or checked startup programs? Have you've already narrowed it down to Windows Defender being the cause?

@JW0914, it on two completely different make and models of Win 10 PC's, though neither is fast as Alienware products, so it seems to be just the way Defender works. The machines run, with MsMpEng at low priority, but disk I/O slows them 'til scan finishes.
